# Slide Horizontally on Vertical Mouse Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a slider that scrolls horizontally if a mouse scrolls on it vertically.

```js
// move slider horizontally on vertical scroll
const target = document.querySelector('.slider')

target.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
  const toLeft  = event.deltaY < 0 && target.scrollLeft > 0
  const toRight = event.deltaY > 0 && target.scrollLeft < target.scrollWidth - target.clientWidth

  if (toLeft || toRight) {
    event.preventDefault()
    target.scrollLeft += event.deltaY
  } 
})
```

```css
.box {
  background: #ccc;
  height: 800px;
}

.slider {
  border: 5px solid black;
  background: #fff;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.item-wrap {
  height: 1000px;
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  min-width: 240px;
  height: 240px;
  font-size: 140px;
  border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  text-align: center;
}

/* add classes */
.test {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

When scrolling down from the top of the page to the top of the slider, I would like the slider to remain fixed until all of the elements are scrolled. When the last item is scrolled (in this case `9`), I would like the window to continue scrolling until the bottom of the page.

Then when the user scrolls from the bottom of the page to the bottom of the slider, I would like the slider to remain fixed until all of the elements are scrolled. When the last item is scrolled (in this case `1`), I would like the window to continue scrolling until the top of the page.

Scrolling to the bottom of the page on [this link](https://career.myrealtrip.com/) shows what I am trying to mimic.

I have noticed that they listen for the window scroll until the top of the slider hits the top of the viewport. Then the slider is given a position of `fixed`. Same concept for when the user scrolls from the bottom of the page to the bottom of the scroller.

But I am uncertain how to implement the dynamic `fixed` position.

Comment: May be this pen Helps you https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/WmyKWO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with `css` position property and `JavaScript` to check conditionally `offsetTop` and `scrollY` and for slide to use css `translate3d` property.

Will need to one extra div `(#pan)` to define height by dynamically after calculating `total width` of each slider item.
**Useful link:** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

*Note: Check on `Full Page` also.*

I hope below snippet will help you a lot.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}

window.onload = function() {
    var wh = window.innerHeight;
    var ww = window.innerWidth;
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
    var pan = document.getElementById('pan');
    var item_wrap = document.getElementById('item_wrap').scrollWidth + wh/1.25;
    pan.style.height = item_wrap + 'px';

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
        if (event.path[1].scrollY >= slider.offsetTop ) {
            if (event.path[1].scrollY < pan.offsetTop + pan.clientHeight) {
                slider.style.position = 'fixed'; //set position fixed
                let aa = event.path[1].scrollY - pan.offsetTop;
                document.getElementById('item_wrap').style.transform = 'translate3d(-' + aa + 'px, 0px, 0px)';   
            }
        }
        if (event.path[1].scrollY <= pan.offsetTop) {
            slider.style.position = 'relative'; //set position relative
        }
    });
}
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
body{
    font-size: Arial;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.box {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10vw;
}

.slider {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 10px 0;
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.item-wrap {
    display: flex;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.82, 0.165, 1);
}
.item {
    display: inline-flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-width: 240px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    font-size: 800%;
    border: 2px solid #d1d1d1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    line-height: 1;
}
.bg-tomato{
    background-color: tomato;
}
.bg-teal{
    background-color: teal;
}
.bg-thistle{
    background-color: thistle;
}
.bg-violet{
    background-color: violet;
}
```

```html
<div class="box bg-tomato">Box - #1</div>
<div class="box bg-thistle">Box - #2</div>
<div class="slider" id="slider">
    <h2>Box - #3 (Slider)</h2>
    <div class="item-wrap" id="item_wrap">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
        <div class="item">11</div>
        <div class="item">12</div>
        <div class="item">13</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pan"></div>

<div class="box bg-teal">Box - #4</div>
<div class="box bg-violet">Box - #5</div>
```

Comment: May I ask for additional explanation on how the one extra div (#pan) defines height dynamically after calculating the total width of each slider item? I am glad the code works, but I have trouble understanding the reasoning behind your calculations.

Comment: Suppose you have 20 slides items and each slide item width is 200px so 20 slides item width will be 20x200 = 4000. Its means slider width is 4000 px but we are scrolling vertically which we have less height of scrolling so we need to define totat width 4000px into (#pan) height for adding more vertically space..

Comment: I see so this is why `pan.style.height` is equal to `document.getElementById('item_wrap').scrollWidth + wh/1.25`. The `scrollWidth` accounts for the 4000 px in your example. You also added additional height `wh` so that all the slides could be seen after 4000 px are scrolled.

Comment: Could I also ask for an explanation as to why there are two if conditions with `if (event.path[1].scrollY >= slider.offsetTop)` and `if (event.path[1].scrollY <= pan.offsetTop)` instead of doing an `if else`? Why does `slider.offsetTop` and `pan.offsetTop` have to be considered separately?

Comment: For more reliable to solve jerking issue it will also work with single if `event.path[1].scrollY < pan.offsetTop + pan.clientHeight` condition for `fixed position`. last one if for position:relative.

Comment: May I also ask how `.box` elements with `position: relative` overlaps the `.slider` that has a `position: fixed`? You don't have a `z-index` property on `.box` so I expected the `.box` elements to go under the `.slider`. Why do they go over the `slider` even though they don't have a higher `z-index`?

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: Let me rephrase my question, why did you add `position: relative` to `.box`?

Comment: Hi @RaeeshAlam, i would like to know is it possible to start 1 in the middle and only show the middle div when user scroll horizontally and apply opacity on left and right div except the middle one. Please reply i am working on a project and need to implement this scroll effect.